# Abridged changelog from svn commit history

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Does anyone have any advice on best practices on automatically generating changelogs from version control system commit logs (specifically SVN).

I am aware that you can use the cli to generate a text file containing all the commit logs but this isn't very customer friendly as it contains every log message. I am after an abridged changelog which only contains the major feature/bug fixes between versions which I am storing in tags.

The best ways I can think of doing this:

- Be rigorous with commit messages on the trunk and use that as my changelog. (At the moment when merging to the trunk we set the commit message to all the commit messages from the branch we are merging from which is easy to do if your are using TortoiseSVN. We would have to stop doing this and only put what we want to appear in the changelog)
- Add a prefix to commit messages we want to form part of the change log and have a script which we can run which only includes messages with that prefix.
- Manually managing a changelog

Comment: The code alone cannot distinguish between what you want and don't want in changelog. Also, the wording in the changelog is sometimes different from the wording of the same issue in svn log. Conclusion: changelog should be edited manually. I do it when I change the version. You could have a svn hook that will reject a commit if version is changed, but changelog is not.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want

> abridged changelog which only contains the major feature/bug fixes
> between versions which I am storing in tags

and have somehow "default" structure of repo (with separate `/tags`) *nothing* stops you from using standard

```
svn log REPO/tags -r LOWTAG:HITAG
```

or the same operaton in TSVN GUI. Yes, you'll have some headache with detecting *numerical values* of your named tags (`-r` option accept only numbers as parameters AFAICR, not mnemonic names of tags)

2. For

> Add a prefix to commit messages we want to form part of the change log
> and have a script

you can do it in more smart way without external scripts: just note options `--search` and `--search-and` in at least SVN 1.8

3. Probably most elegant and usable way can be mix of 1+2 with additions. Add to **needed in changelog** revisions (on commit or later) special custom revison-property, fill it with ready-to-publish text, and output in svn log only  revisions

- In requested range
- With defined revprop
- With needed signal-string